# Can someone explain how the head of ResNet50 changing in this code snippet?

Tags: python, deep-learning, resnet

```
headModel = baseModel.output
headModel = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(7, 7))(headModel)
headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
headModel = Dense(512, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
headModel = Dense(len(lb.classes_), activation="softmax")(headModel)
```

I can see 2 activation functions are being used here. Is it using relu for the hidden layers and then softmax for the output layer? Also does it mean input layer = 512?

Comment: Try plotting your model using `tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, 'my_first_model.png', show_shapes=True)` or see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63604713/in-tensorflow-is-it-possible-to-see-another-models-build-structure/63605023#63605023) if you have a model file.

Comment: `tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, 'my_first_model.png', show_shapes=True)` worked fine for me. Thanks a lot